# Returning constructor arguments in function, calls the constructor on return

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constructor, return, return-type

I ran into some code that surprised me. This compiles in Visual Studio 2012 and runs just fine.

#### The Description Class

```
class Description {
public:
    Description(bool valid = false);
    ~Description(void);
};
```

#### Main

```
Description functionThatReturnsADescription()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    Description theDescription = functionThatReturnsADescription();
}
```

My confusion is with the `functionThatReturnsADescription()` method; how is it legal to return any object other than Description? If I set it to `return 1`, it calls the Description constructor with `valid = true`. If I set it to `return false` or `return 0`, it calls the Description constructor with `valid = false`.

Does this mean a C++ compiler *always* calls the functions' return type constructor with the arguments of the return statement?? How did I not know that before?! I would have swore this wasn't legal C++.

Comment: try to read something about the explicit keyword

Comment: @AnatolyS, I'm quite aware of the `explicit` keyword. I'm just surprised that the return statement invokes the constructor when returning; I always assumed it just copied an already-constructed object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how is it legal to return any object other than Description?

You can return any type that's implicitly convertible to `Description`. In this case, any numeric type can be converted to `bool` via standard conversions, then to `Description` via the non-explicit constructor.

You could prevent this conversion by declaring the constructor `explicit`, if you like. It's a good idea to make that a habit, to avoid unexpected conversions like this one.

> Does this mean a C++ compiler always calls the functions' return type constructor with the arguments of the return statement??

If the types don't match, and there is a suitable non-explicit constructor to use for the conversion, yes.

> How did I not know that before?!

C++ is a complicated language. After fifteen years, I still keep finding things I didn't know.

Comment: It really never occurred to me that "a convertable type" could mean "a type which can be passed to a constructor to form a valid object of another type". Isn't it a bit weird to say "this object is of type bool" and then convert it by saying "an object of type bool is almost the same as a Description to which a bool is passed"?? That seems completely wrong behavior to me. I would fully expect the compiler to throw an error. I'm trying to find some C++ documentation on this, but I can't find it. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: @jmbeck: The weirdness comes because you've given the type an implicit conversion constructor, which specifically says it should be convertible from `bool`. As I said, make it `explicit` if that conversion doesn't make sense; then the compiler will give the error you want. (Perhaps one could argue that that should be the default; but it isn't, so you'll just have to learn to use `explicit` when appropriate). User-defined type conversions are described in C++ 12.3 if you want the gory details; they can use a non-explicit conversion constructor or operator.

Comment: I don't think of a constructor as "is used to convert from input arguments". I think of a constructor as a function which builds a specific type _from_ the input arguments. Specifying the constructor as `explicit` prevents conversions of the input arguments, such as float to int, or int to boolean. Standard conversions make sense because they describe the types as a subset or superset of each other. I don't see that same relationship with an object's constructor and the constructors input arguments.

Comment: Section 12.3.1 of the [2012 C++ Specification](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) (pdf) just blew my mind. I had no idea that was legal C++.

Comment: @jmbeck: "Specifying the constructor as explicit prevents conversions of the input arguments": No. It does exactly what I said it does: prevents the constructor from being used for implicit cnoversions.

Comment: @jmbeck: " I don't see that same relationship with an object's constructor and the constructors input arguments.": For some classes (like this one) it doesn't make sense, so the constructor should be explicit. For others, it does: consider `complex z = 1.0;`. A constructor is the only available construct that could convert from a built-in type, so that's what we use.

Answer (score 1):

`1` gets implicitly converted to `true`, so the constructor accepting a `bool` is chosen.

To prevent this implicit conversion, you can mark the constructor as `explicit`, in which case only

```
return Description(1);
```

would work.

Answer (score 1):

The return value `1` gets implicitly converted to boolean `true` which is then passed as an argument to the constructor. A `Description` object gets created implicitly using the constructor `Description(bool valid = false);`.

It is to be noted that two implicit conversions are happening here: 1 → true → Description. You can prevent the second conversion by making the constructor `explicit`. Change the declaration of the constructor to

```
explicit Description(bool valid = false);
```

However, the first conversion would still happen i.e. one can still do `return Description(1);`.

Refer: [What does the explicit keyword in C++ mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121162/183120)